# Разбить строку на массив js

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

У меня есть строка

```
'${user name} ${action} ${what} some_text'
```

Есть ли какой-нибудь нормальный способ с помощью split разбить эту строку на массив?

Ожидается:

```
['${user name}', '${action}', '${what}', 'some_text']
```

Очень желательно решение без регулярок, если такое возможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием регулярного выражения

```
var str = '${user name} ${action} ${what} some_text';
var re = /(\$\{.*?\}|\w+)/g;
var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);
```

Результат

```
 ["${user name}", "${action}", "${what}", "some_text"]
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/q5hugvtx/

Comment: Такой вопрос, а если строка будет с восклицательным знаком, который буде стоять в притык, и его тоже надо поместить в отдельную ячейку массива например:

`"Hello ${user name}!"`
ожадется 

`['Hello', '${user name}', "!"]`

Comment: @pan4o_dp, http://jsfiddle.net/q5hugvtx/2/